# Regex match Wikipedia internal article links

Tags: java, regex

I want to regex match text in Wikipedia article source code with following rules:

---

1. **Match only links to internal articles.** So don't match links with any namespaces like files, categories, users, ... etc (complete list of these namespaces [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces))

   - Example link to match `[[Without|namespace]]`
   - Example links NOT to match `[[Category:Nope]]`, `[[File:Nopeish]]` etc.

---

2. **Match only links having delimiter "|"**. Links with this symbol are displayed in article with different text as the title of article they are referring to

   - Example link to match `[[Something|else]]`
   - Example link NOT to match `[[text]]`

---

3. **Match links in two groups**

   - Example link to match `[[Something|else]]` will be matched into two groups with text:

     1. group: `"Something"`
     2. group: `"else"`

---

I have tested this and so far I've come up with following regex: `\[\[(?!.+?:)(.+?)\|(.+?)\]\]` which is not working as expected since it also matches text like this:

```
[[Problem]] non link text [[Another link|problemAgain]]
  ^------------ group 1 (wrong) -------^ ^-group 2 -^

[[This should be|matched|]]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lO7wF7/2)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a negated character class instead of `.+?`,

```
\[\[(?!.+?:)([^\]\[]+)\|([^\]\[]+)\]\]
```

Java regex would be,

```
"\\[\\[(?!.+?:)([^\\]\\[]+)\\|([^\\]\\[]+)\\]\\]"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lO7wF7/3)

OR

simply you could do like this,

```
\[\[([^\]\[:]+)\|([^\]\[:]+)\]\]
```

Java regex would be,

```
"\\[\\[([^\\]\\[:]+)\\|([^\\]\\[:]+)\\]\\]"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lO7wF7/4)